# Filter Windows Event Viewer based on information inside the event itself

Tags: windows, windows-server, windows-server-2019, event-viewer

I have a large number of events like:

```
Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command
EventId: 20101

Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [dbo].[Reports] AS [r]
        WHERE [r].[status] = N'Queued') THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END
```

When I look at other similar events, I noticed that they also have an EventId of 20101. I hoped that, based on this, I could filter those out:

[image]

I was also hoping that I could filter them out based on the category `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command`. However, the *Task category* dropdown is disabled.

Even when I apply this filter, it appears to have no effect whatsoever: I still see a large number of events of this type. That's apparently because *Event ID* in the main screen appears to be 1000 and the *Task Category* appears to be **None** for all .NET-related events:

[image]

I'm not sure how I can filter on the Category and Event ID in the event itself. Do I need to change my application code somehow to set the `Event ID` and `Task Category` fields? Or is there some way that I can do this from Event Viewer itself?

Comment: Event Viewer supports using XPath queries to filter based on the properties of the event. Can you add the XML (select event > details tab > xml view) of an example event to your question? It looks like .NET just throws everything into a single field, so it will probably just be a basic text filter.